# How to use react-final-from calculated fields with an array of objects

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form, final-form

I have an array of objects in `react-final-form` with a `sum` field. At the end I would like to count the total of all sums. So I'm using calculated fields from `final-form-calculate` like this:

```
const calculator = createDecorator({
  field: /day\[\d\]\.sum/, // when a field matching this pattern changes...
  updates: (value, name, allValues) => {
    console.log("Updated field", value, name);
    // ...update the total to the result of this function
    total: (ignoredValue, allValues) =>
      (allValues.day || []).reduce((sum, value) => sum + Number(value || 0), 0);
    return {};
  }
});
```

When I enter values in the inputs, `console.log` is called, but the total is not updated. I guess it doesn't pick the values from the necessary fields. How can I fix it? Here is my codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/react-final-form-calculated-fields-hkd65?fontsize=14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some syntactical error in your code snippet, specifically the calculator function. This version of the function works:

```
const calculator = createDecorator({
  field: /day\[\d\]\.sum/, // when a field matching this pattern changes...
  updates:  {
    // ...update the total to the result of this function
    total: (ignoredValue, allValues) => (allValues.day || []).reduce((sum, value) => sum + Number(value.sum || 0), 0),
  }
});
```

There are two major changes I did,

- In the reduce call back, I changed `Number(value || 0)` to `Number(value.sum || 0)`
- I also set the `updates` property to an object instead of a function.

Answer (score 1):

Final-form-calculate docs, say the the updater can be:

> Either an object of updater functions or a function that generates
>   updates for multiple fields.

In your example, the code was some kind of mix between them. Also `value.sum` contains the entered numbers, not `value`.

Here's how to do it correctly, with an **object of updater functions**:

```
const calculator = createDecorator({
    field: /day\[\d\]\.sum/,
    updates: {
        total: (ignoredValue, allValues) => (allValues.day || []).reduce((sum, value) => sum + Number(value.sum || 0), 0)
    }
});
```

or **updates for multiple fields** (just one actually, but could be more):

```
const calculator = createDecorator({
    field: /day\[\d\]\.sum/,
    updates: (ignoredValue, fieldName, allValues) => {
        const total = (allValues.day || []).reduce((sum, value) => sum + Number(value.sum || 0), 0);
        return { total };
    }
});
```

Also, here are the updater Typescript definitions, for reference:

```
export type UpdatesByName = {
  [FieldName: string]: (value: any, allValues?: Object, prevValues?: Object) => any
}

export type UpdatesForAll = (
  value: any,
  field: string,
  allValues?: Object,
  prevValues?: Object,
) => { [FieldName: string]: any }

export type Updates = UpdatesByName | UpdatesForAll
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply!  But I chose another answer, as it pointed out my mistake. If I could, I would choose both!